# using git to scan source code to generate todo list etc

Tags: git, todo

I have lots of comments in the source code marked as future todos.

e.g. `#todo:improve api for common syntax`

etc.

I am using git for version control.

I would like to list all my `todo`, with something like

```
git list todo.
```

If no such plugin exists, can you guide me, how do I write one myself?

Comment: What does searching a directory for `TODO`s have to do with `git`?

Comment: could you answer the question, so that I can select it as correct answer. It worked like charm. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming all your todos are single-line comments, you could use `git grep`:

```
git grep '#todo'
```

You could then use redirects to store it for future use, e.g.:

```
git grep '#todo' > ~/Documents/my_project_todo.txt
```